# bash script ends independently debian

Tags: bash

I have next bash script:

```
a=$(hostname)
inotifywait -m -r -e attrib -e modify -e move -e create -e delete /etc /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin |
while read path action file; do
    echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S) the file '$file' was $action in directory $path by $USER" | nc syslog port -w 1
    echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S) the file '$file' was $action in directory $path by $USER" | mail -s 'Something changed on '$a me@domain.com
done
```

I run it as "nohup script.sh &" and everyting looks fine.
I see it in processes and it really works when i change something.
But after a while the processes disappear :(

I use this same scheme on different servers, on one server it works uninterrupted but on second server it's stopping.
Please give some advice? maybe something with kernel?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything written to `nohup.out`?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the script too to see what happens right before it exits also.

Comment: nohup.out has standard output "Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while! Watches established."

Comment: after add `set -x` in nohup.out i see `++ hostname
+ a=mtsfe
+ inotifywait -m -r -e attrib -e modify -e move -e create -e delete /etc /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin 
+ read path action file
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.`